# isset() not allowed as callback for array_filter()

Tags: php

If you want to remove null values from an array, then passing them through a simple `array_filter()` and using the built in `isset()` function seems like a great option:

```
$dairyFree = true;
$toppings = [
 'tomato',
 'oregano',
 'pepperoni',
 ($dairyFree) ? null : 'cheese',
];

$toppings = array_filter($toppings, 'isset');
```

Pretty simple, but using `isset()` in `array_filter()` raises the following warning:

**Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'isset' not found or invalid function name.**

It is easy enough to wrap the same code inside a closure, but my question is – why would php balk at the `isset()` function and not other internal functions like `strlen()`?

Comment: You shall write a custom function that call isset inside.

Comment: _Because this is a **language construct and not a function**, it cannot be called using variable functions._ Or be used where a function is expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `isset` is not exactly a function, it is a construct like `echo`. If you are just looking for removing `null` values from the array, without `isset` parameter is good enough.

```
<?php
    $dairyFree = true;
    $toppings = [
      'tomato',
      'oregano',
      'pepperoni',
      ($dairyFree) ? null : 'cheese',
    ];
    $toppings = array_filter($toppings);
    print_r($toppings);
?>
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tomato
    [1] => oregano
    [2] => pepperoni
)
```

Comment: Important to note that the default functionality of array_filter will filter out any value that loosely equates to false.  This means null, false, 0, or an empty string.

Comment: Good answer. Interesting that these language constructs (like `list` and apparently `isset`) fall under the documentation as functions. In my particular application I needed `null` values to fall out, and not just falsy values.

Comment: @jpschroeder What you need here is `not_is_null()` , but in php only `is_null()` is a function :)

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
$toppings = array_filter($toppings, function($a){return isset($a);});
```

UPDATE: forget it, you noticed this in your question.